# Задача исключительно с циклом While требует доработки (новичок)

Tags: python, while

Задача:
Когда у банка есть финансовые проблемы, правительство может вернуть депозит клиента, если он меньше 700 000. Процентная ставка по конкретному депозиту составляет 7,1% годовых. Проценты выплачиваются на тот же депозит в конце года, и рассчитывается новое значение процентов.

Узнайте, сколько лет потребуется, чтобы сумма депозита превысила стоимость, охраняемую государством.

Мой код (я чувствую, что с ним что-то не то, но не могу понять, ЧТО ИМЕННО. Истина крутится рядом с year.):

```
deposit=int(input())
year = 0
while deposit < 700000:
    deposit = deposit + (deposit * 0.071)
    year =+ 1
print(year)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас ошибка в коде.
Вместо `year =+ 1` нужно `year += 1`.

`year =+ 1` каждый раз присваивает переменной `year` единицу.